# Some phones incorrectly setIcon to submenu

Tags: list, colors, drawable, submenu

I have some phones android <= 9 which applies last color for all list items in submenu.

How to fix this?

```
.subscribe(labels -> labels.forEach(label -> {
          Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_circle_outline);
          DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.parseColor(label.getLabelColor());
          subMenu.add(LABEL_GROUP, label.get_id(), label.get_id(), label.getName()).setIcon(drawable);
          }
          ), error -> Log.e(TAG, "", error)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(label.getLabelColor()), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```